# Accessing individual particle color

Tags: particles, color

For a long time I've been trying to change particle colors depending on where the individual particle is located.

My latest unsuccesfull attempt was using Animation Nodes, but I fear it is not, (yet), possible in Blender?

My intention is to illustrate the transfer of heat to dust suspended in gas as it passes through a complex system.

Any comments on this question?

Kind regards

Ryosei

Answer (score 1):

You can do this within a Cycles shader using the particle info node. One of it's outputs is "location", which is the world space location of the particle than an object is being cloned onto. By splitting this vector with the a Separate XYZ node, you can control a color ramp based on a particular axis:
[image: example node setup using particle info to drive a ramp]

In this example, I've used the Z-component of Particle Info > Location, modified with with math nodes, and fed it through a color ramp to colorize the spheres based on their height.

Comment: continued....
I am familiar with this feature, but unfortunately I'm not able to use it here.
My particles are moving through an intricate system of cyclones and other vessels, and their raise in temperature is not directly corresponding to any main direction of motion, e.g. -Z.
My attempt with Animation Nodes was to use the "Is Inside"-node, but I can only make this affect all particles at once, not the individual particle whose location I am able to detect using AN.